# Show static block content for particular dates and times in magento 1.8

Tags: php, datetime, magento, magento-1.8

Hi we are planning to create a whole weeks worth of sales leading up to Black Friday. Usually when we have a sale I stay up until midnight and switch all the content on the site then change it back at midnight the next night.

For this week-long sale I would like to create a static block for each day in advance and then somehow make our homepage content switch between the blocks on midnight of each night. I am not sure of the best way to approach this.

I want to avoid making one big page and switching the content using JS as I don't want the links to each sale visible in the source code for any clever shoppers!

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Glynn